# Remote controlling java webstart apps - design

Tags: java, http, rmi, java-web-start

A java client is delivered to the customer via webstart and reports to a servlet that

1. It has started.
2. And that it is performing a task n times per second.

An admin on the servlet side with access to information in 1 and 2 decides that the client now needs to perform a task (n+x) times per second.

What would be the best way to do this? I do not want to put in a polling mechanism in the client.

Would I be able to use RMI to set the value on the client OR clients when multiple instances are invoked.